# Declaring multiple XSLT variables of the same name in the same scope

Tags: xslt

I know that XSLT variables once initialized cannot change their respective values.
Saxon-PE 9.2.0.6 allows the following syntax:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="myVar" select="'asdex upgrade'" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$myVar" /><xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:variable name="myVar" select="'Wendelstein'" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$myVar" /><xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

with this output:

```
asdex upgrade
Wendelstein
```

So what is happening here? Obviously this code is not in contradiction to the fact that variables are immutable in XSLT, or else the Saxon processor would not process it. Am I creating two variables with the same name here (with their scopes local to the given template)? If so, do I have means to access the first variable after the second one was created, or did it cease to exist, or is it overshadowed in the XSLT processor's symbol tables? Or what gives?

Thanks for any enlightenment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#scope-of-variables on details, it explains

> For any variable-binding element, there is a region (more
>   specifically, a set of element nodes) of the stylesheet within which
>   the binding is visible. The set of variable bindings in scope for an
>   XPath expression consists of those bindings that are visible at the
>   point in the stylesheet where the expression occurs.

and

> A local variable binding element is visible for all following siblings
>   and their descendants, with two exceptions: it is not visible in any
>   region where it is shadowed by another variable binding, and it is not
>   visible within the subtree rooted at an xsl:fallback instruction that
>   is a sibling of the variable binding element. The binding is not
>   visible for the xsl:variable or xsl:param element itself.
>
> [Definition: A binding shadows another binding if the binding occurs
>   at a point where the other binding is visible, and the bindings have
>   the same name. ] It is not an error if a binding established by a
>   local xsl:variable or xsl:param shadows a global binding. In this
>   case, the global binding will not be visible in the region of the
>   stylesheet where it is shadowed by the other binding.

So the second `xsl:variable name="myVar"` shadows the first one.

Comment: Ah, thanks. The specification states it quite clearly. Thanks for the link, I'll obviously have to do some reading there.